# search customer to update card details stripe

Tags: php, stripe-payments

im trying to make a page that permit to update card to the customers.
to update card detail i take the example of stripe documentation and thats it:

```
if (isset($_POST['stripeToken'])){
    $customer = \Stripe\Customer::all(["limit" => 100, "email" => $mail]);
    $customerid = intval($customer->id);
  try {
    $cu = \Stripe\Customer::update(
      $customerid,
      [
        'source' => $_POST['stripeToken'],
      ]
    );
    echo "Your card details have been updated!";
  }
  catch(\Stripe\Exception\CardException $e) {

    $body = $e->getJsonBody();
    $err  = $body['error'];
    $error = $err['message'];
  }
}

?>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form action="updatecard.php" method="POST">
  <script
    src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
    data-key="<?php echo $params['public_test_key']; ?>"
    data-image="img/logo-b.jpeg"
    data-name="Your Website Name  f"
    data-panel-label="Update Card Details"
    data-label="Update Card Details"
    data-allow-remember-me=false
    data-locale="auto">
  </script>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

the problem is on the only thing that i write:

> $customer = \Stripe\Customer::all(["limit" => 100, "email" => $mail]);

i also tried without limit value but stripe log gives me always this error:

```
   "error": {
     "code": "resource_missing",
     "doc_url": "https://stripe.com/docs/error-codes/resource-missing",
     "message": "No such customer: 0",
     "param": "id",
     "type": "invalid_request_error"
```

i have 2 questions about that:

the first: how to pass mail from stripe form to POST method?

the second: where i wrong by searching a customer with email?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The API method you are calling is the List Customers [API](https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/list). This doesn't return one customer but a list of customers, with either 0, 1 or multiple customers in it. This means that the object itself is a Stripe List and the elements are inside the `data` array.

You need to change this line of code:

```
$customerid = intval($customer->id);
```

Instead, you want to check if there are any results and then accessing the id of the first customer if any:

```
$customers = \Stripe\Customer::all(["limit" => 100, "email" => $mail]);
if(count($customers->data == 0 )
{
    // handle cases where there are no match
}
else
{
    $customerid = $customers->data[0]->id;
    // then update
}
```